# Does Db2 on IBM cloud support text search feature?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

For the DB2 on IBM Cloud, does it support text search feature?
I'd like to enable the Text Search feature for the Db2 on cloud resource, but couldn't find any document/resource about it. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your plan, i.e. whether __you__ control the hosts and Db2-instances or whether IBM does.  Pay enough cash per month and you get to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Db2 on Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-about) does not include the Text Search feature. It is a managed system and designed for transactional workloads. Text Search would be counter-productive. But you could store text in character-based columns and use LIKE or REGEX-based expressions to perform text search.

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik! 
One more question here, would you please help to introduce more on why it would be counter-productive for DBaaS?

Comment: IMHO the Db2 on Cloud (transactional workloads) and Db2 Warehouse on Cloud (analytics) workloads are configured (HW / SW) for optimal performance. Text Search requires a side-engine which probably is not used by many of the targeted audience. Thus, I suspect, it is a business and performance decision not to include the text search engine. But you could set up your own Db2 on IBM Cloud and use text search.